# Inconsistent type of *args

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash, arguments, memoization

I'm trying to write a generic memoization function in python 2.7 (no issue in 3.x)

```
def init_memoize():
    fns = dict()
    def memoize(fn, *args):
        if fn not in fns:
            fns[fn] = dict()
        print type(args)       # prints "<type 'tuple'>"
        print args in fns[fn]  # throws the error
        if args not in fns[fn]:
            fns[fn][args] = fn(*args)
        return fns[fn][args]
    return memoize
memoize = init_memoize()

memoize(sorted, range(5))
memoize(sorted, range(10))
```

When I try and run this code, I get an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` at the noted line, but immediately before, I verify that the type of args is a hashable tuple.

Can someone clarify why the type of `args` changes?

Comment: You don't show any code where you actually call `memoize`.  What are you passing as the the args?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tuple with a list inside it is still unhashable for the same reason that a list is unhashable.

```
>>> args = ([],)
>>> type(args)
<type 'tuple'>
>>> d = {args: None}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> hash(args)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that range returns a list in 2.7